# How to add a WMS server without {bbox-epsg-3857} in MapBox-gl

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, wms, react-map-gl

i am trying to add a wms server to a Mapbox-gl map.
as the documentation sais i need to add the wms Server with a ["{bbox-epsg-3857}" replacement token](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#tiled-sources). the Problem is, that it seems that the server i want to use does not really work well with this: the layer kind of shows, but only shows white tiles (or empty tiles).

this is the query i am using:

[https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wms/senstadt/k_luftbild2021_rgb?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=k_luftbild2021_rgb&styles=gdi_default&crs=EPSG%3A4258&width=256&height=256&format=image%2Fpng&bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}](https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wms/senstadt/k_luftbild2021_rgb?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=k_luftbild2021_rgb&styles=gdi_default&crs=EPSG%3A4258&width=256&height=256&format=image%2Fpng&bbox=%7Bbbox-epsg-3857%7D)

looking at the network traffic, mapbox converts this into EPSG:3857, but the server does not know where this is. This is one of the tiles Mapbox creates:

https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wms/senstadt/k_luftbild2021_rgb?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=k_luftbild2021_rgb&styles=gdi_default&crs=EPSG%3A4258&width=256&height=256&format=image%2Fpng&bbox=1492968.036466062,6890645.2258520685,1493273.7845792025,6890950.973965209

looking at the bbox, its obviouse that this should not be EPSG:3857, but rather EPSG25833 for example.

The Problem now is that other Tokens then {bbox-epsg-3857} seem to be not available, but the server listens to EPSG:25833.

Is there any way to create the boundingbox in an other EPSG? how would i solve this issue?

this is how i try to get this to work (using react-map-gl)

```
<Source
  key={`${entry.id}_${entry.displayName}_wmssource`}
  type="raster"
  tiles={[
    `https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wms/senstadt/k_luftbild2021_rgb?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=k_luftbild2021_rgb&styles=gdi_default&crs=EPSG%3A4258&width=256&height=256&format=image%2Fpng&bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}`,
  ]}
  tileSize={256}
  attribution="" // TODO: add attribution
>
  <Layer
    key={`${entry.id}_${i}_${entry.displayName}_outline`}
    type="raster"
    id={`${entry.id}_${i}_${entry.displayName}_outline`}
  />
</Source>
```

Any Help would be awesome!!

Comment: As the documentation states, `By providing a URL to a WMS server that supports EPSG:3857 (or EPSG:900913) as a source of tiled data. The server URL should contain a "{bbox-epsg-3857}"`  but the service doesn't support that CRS so you can't use it.    You might be able to cascade through another WMS service,  for example GeoServer and MapServer software can do this, or you could use MapProxy